# Android, How to stop Service playing music when pausing app ,

Tags: android, service

I am building a simple android application and it has two Activities and a IntentService.  My IntentService plays music over every activity(thats what I want) but if I leave the app the music still plays (example: if I press the home button it will take me to the desktop, putting my activity in the onpause state but the music from that app is still playing).  Any help would be appreciated....

code below

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent serviceIntent= new Intent(this, BackgroundMusic.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);



}




public void ShipPick(View view){

    Intent activityIntent= new Intent(this, ShipChoiceActivity.class);
    startActivity(activityIntent);

}


}
```

Background Music Service

```
public class BackgroundMusic extends IntentService {

MediaPlayer mp;

 public BackgroundMusic() {
      super("BackgroundMusic");
  }


 Handler HN = new Handler(); 


 private class PlayMusic implements Runnable {



       public void PLayMusic(){

       }

       public void run(){
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.musicfile);
        mp.start();
       }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    HN.post(new PlayMusic()); 

 }

 public void onPause() {

        mp.pause();
        }

 public void onResume() {

     mp.start();
     }

 protected void onStop() {

     mp.stop();
     mp = null;
     }


 }
```

second activity

```
public class ShipChoiceActivity extends Activity {



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ship_choice);


}

}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.starwars"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <service android:name=".BackgroundMusic" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ship.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ShipChoiceActivity"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: bind the service to the activity.

Comment: In the onPause function of your activity, stop that service.

Answer (score 1):

For controlling `BackgroundMusic` Service from Activity you will need to use custom `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate with service when application is going in onpause state.

Register BroadcastReceiver In BackgroundMusic :

```
    public class MusicServiceBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

                    if(<Match for action>){
                      if Action is for pause then call pause for MediaPlayer
                    }else{
                      if Action for Play ...
                    }
        }

    } 
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    //... Register BroadcastReceiver
    registerReceiver(new MusicServiceBroadCast(), new IntentFilter(
     "com.xx.PAUSE_MUSIC_ACTION"));
    HN.post(new PlayMusic()); 

 }
```

Send BroadcastReceiver from Activity `onPause` :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("com.xx.PAUSE_MUSIC_ACTION");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```